# Left Join по условию(4 таблицы) CASE

Tags: mysql, join, case

Вопрос по SQL.
Есть 4 таблицы со след структурой:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `main_table` (
  `id` int(7) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `t1` (
  `id` int(7) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `col11` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `col12` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `col13` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `col14` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=innoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `t2` (
  `id` int(7) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `col21` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `col22` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=innoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `t3` (
  `id` int(7) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `col31` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `col32` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `col33` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=innoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Таблица main_table содержит все id, которые присутствуют в таблицах t1,t2,t3, в этих 3х таблицах id не пересекаются.
Необходимо объединить таблицы t1,t2,t3 с таблицей main_table в зависимости от типа(main_table.type).

Я написал следующий вариант

```
Select main_table.*,
 CASE main_table.type
WHEN "type_1" THEN t1.col11
WHEN "type_2" THEN t2.col21
ELSE THEN t3.col31 END
 CASE main_table.type
WHEN "type_1" THEN t1.col12
WHEN "type_2" THEN t2.col22
ELSE THEN t3.col32 END
 CASE main_table.type
WHEN "type_1" THEN t1.col13
WHEN "type_3" THEN t3.col33 END
 from main_table
LEFT JOIN t1 ON(main_table.id = t1.id)
LEFT JOIN t2 ON(main_table.id = t2.id)
LEFT JOIN t3 ON(main_table.id = t3.id)
```

В этом случае если в таблицах много столбцов, будет очень длинный запрос и много проверок.

Можно ли в выбрать сразу все столбцы или перечислить без повторных проверок. Или подскажите вариант более лаконичный, а то я уверен что я извращение сотворил.

Есть еще вот такой вариант:

```
 Select * from main_table
 LEFT JOIN t1 ON(main_table.id = t1.id AND main_table.type = "type_1")
 LEFT JOIN t2 ON(main_table.id = t2.id AND main_table.type = "type_2")
 LEFT JOIN t3 ON(main_table.id = t3.id AND main_table.type = "type_3")`
```

в данном случае работает так как надо, вот только необходимо исключить null значения из двух остальных таблиц

В общем смысл я думаю понятен, нужно объединить 2 таблицы, первая всегда одна и та же, вторая выбирается из 3 в зависимости от значения поля тип в первой таблице.

Залил пример на sqlfiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/03869/1
со следующими данными:

```
INSERT INTO `main_table` (`id`, `type`) VALUES
(1,'type_1'),
(2,'type_2'),
(3,'type_2'),
(4,'type_1'),
(5,'type_3'),
(6,'type_3'),
(7,'type_2'),
(8,'type_1'),
(9,'type_3');

INSERT INTO `t1` (`id`, `col11`, `col12`, `col13`, `col14`) VALUES
(1,'1', '1', '1', '1'),
(4,'1', '1', '1', '1'),
(8,'1', '1', '1', '1');

INSERT INTO `t2` (`id`, `col21`, `col22`) VALUES
(2,'2', '2'),
(3,'2', '2'),
(7,'2', '2');

INSERT INTO `t3` (`id`, `col31`, `col32`, `col33`) VALUES
(5,'3', '3', '3'),
(6,'3', '3', '3'),
(9,'3', '3', '3');
```

со следующим запросом:

```
Select * from main_table
 LEFT JOIN t1 ON(main_table.id = t1.id AND main_table.type = "type_1")
 LEFT JOIN t2 ON(main_table.id = t2.id AND main_table.type = "type_2")
 LEFT JOIN t3 ON(main_table.id = t3.id AND main_table.type = "type_3")
```

Результат

```
id  type    id  col11   col12   col13   col14   id  col21   col22   id  col31   col32   col33
1   type_1  1   1   1   1   1   (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)
2   type_2  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  2   2   2   (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)
3   type_2  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  3   2   2   (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)
4   type_1  4   1   1   1   1   (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)
5   type_3  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  5   3   3   3
6   type_3  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  6   3   3   3
7   type_2  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  7   2   2   (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)
8   type_1  8   1   1   1   1   (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)
9   type_3  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  9   3   3   3
```

Необходимы только непустые значения, т.е. выбор на каждой строке главной таблицы из нужной присоединенной таблицы по значению type из главной.

Конечный результат должен быть такого вида:

```
1   type_1  1   1   1   1   1                           
2   type_2  2   2   2               
3   type_2  3   2   2               
4   type_1  4   1   1   1   1                           
5   type_3  5   3   3   3
6   type_3  6   3   3   3
7   type_2  7   2   2               
8   type_1  8   1   1   1   1                           
9   type_3  9   3   3   3
```

Скорее всего я просто не до конца понимаю работу самого SQL для последовательности выборки такого вида и хочу что бы при выборе строки из main_table, к примеру с типом type_1 SQL даже не смотрел в таблицы t2,t3 не затрачивая на это ресурсы пусть и минимальные, а работал лишь с таблицей t1. Постараюсь сейчас привести полный пример с CASE и COALESCE которые отобразят желаемый результат.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34015/discussion-on-question-by-homko-left-join--4--case).

Comment: получается писать в чат?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 select * from main_table
   LEFT JOIN t1 ON(main_table.id = t1.id) WHERE main_table.type = "type_1"
union
 select *,null,null from main_table
   LEFT JOIN t2 ON(main_table.id = t2.id) WHERE main_table.type = "type_2"
union
 select *,null from main_table
   LEFT JOIN t3 ON(main_table.id = t3.id) WHERE main_table.type = "type_3"
```

Вместо `*` конечно лучше перечислять нужные столбцы, что бы встали именно на те места, где предполагались и добавление нового столбца в какую либо таблицу не сломало запрос. Ну и `LEFT` возможно не обязателен, зависит от того есть ли у вас какие либо записи например с type_1, которых нет в t1 и которые все таки нужны в результате

**UPD** Для случая, описанного в комментарии:

```
 select * from main_table
   JOIN t1 ON(main_table.id = t1.id) WHERE main_table.type = "type_1"
union
 select *,null,null from main_table
   JOIN t2 ON(main_table.id = t2.id) WHERE main_table.type = "type_2"
union
 select *,null from main_table
   JOIN t3 ON(main_table.id = t3.id) WHERE main_table.type = "type_3"
union
 select *,null,null,null,null from main_table
  where type not in("type_1","type_2","type_3")
```

Comment: Мне кажется автор хочет вообще чтоб `null` не было. Если я правильно понял. Что вроде бы в данном случае не избежать.. Иначе бы идею с `union` я бы уже нарисовал бы.

Comment: судя по его данным, вот в этом  `WHERE main_table.type =...` я никакого смысла не вижу

Comment: @АлексейШиманский По его первоначальному примеру с `case` вроде как понятно, что он хочет получить. но case ему понятное дело кажется громоздким

Comment: @splash58 Учитывая left в каждой из частей union без where выберутся строки других типов без приклеенных данных. в итоге строки задвоятся с данными и без. кроме того я решил ограничить выборку из main в каждом блоке, что бы не нагружать базу лишней работой

Comment: Да, наверное, и правда. тока знать б еще, чего автор вопроса хочет :)))

Comment: Приведу пример.
Есть таблица с предметами, которые есть у персонажей, это main_table.
t1 - это оружие со своими полями, которые не нужны предметам иного типа.(поэтому решил вынести в отдельную таблицу)
t2 - это части брони со своими полями,
t3 - это все остальные предметы так же разных типов, но уже решил не создавать для каждого отельную, просто оружие и броня значительно отличается по полям

соответственно если я хочу посмотреть все свои вещи мне нужно выбрать из всех таблиц, можно сделать это конечно с помощью нескольких запросов, но если каждый будет просматривать ...

Comment: @Homko Вы желаемый результат выборки тогда в вопросе укажите. потому как по данному вашему комментарию мне кажется union решает именно то, что вы хотите. Хотя наверное тогда надо было бы сделать без LEFT, зато добавить еще union с выборкой типов не 1,2,3 - т.е. всех типов для которых нет доп. таблиц